# How to fix this code of "1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! +....+ 1/n!"

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

So, I am trying to write a program to compute the value of the series 1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! + .. + 1/n!. I think this is a pretty easy question to solve. But, the 1/0! i.e. the 1st term of the series is where it is creating all the problems for me. Please help me out. Please pardon for the silly mistakes if I have made since I started learning C++ 2 months ago and I am trying to solve various problems ever since.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fact(int j)
{
    int facto = 1;
    if (j == 0) {
        return facto;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= j; i++) {
            facto = facto * i;
        }
        return facto;
    }
}

int main()
{

    int n, p;
    float sum = 0, k;
    cout << "Enter the value of n: " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        p = fact(i);
        cout << p << endl;
        k = 1 / p;
        cout << k << endl;
        sum = sum + k;
    }
    cout << "Sum is: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 questions :

1) When I am giving 0 as input, I am getting 0(i.e. the value of sum) as output(but, I am expecting to get 1) and, when I am giving 1 as input, it is giving 1 as output(expecting 2 as output). Please help me in pointing out the loophole.

2) When I am giving 0 as input, it is not printing the values of 'p' and 'k' but any input greater than 0 is showing the values of 'p' and 'k' for each time it completes the loop. Why ??

Comment: `k = 1/p ;` will be 0 (unless p==1) because of integer division.

Comment: If `n` is zero, the loop in `main()` is never executed.  That means `fact()` is never called, and `sum` is never changed from its initial value of zero.      Also, if you want to compute `e` (the base of natural logarithms) simply call `std::exp(1.0)` - no loop needed.

Comment: @Peter Ok, that's where I made the mistake, got it. But, by changing the condition from i<n to i<=n also hampers the problem itself. In this series, 1/0! is the 1st term, 1/1! is the 2nd term and therefore, there are n+1 terms. Suppose, if user gives input 5(no of terms), the variable 'sum' should print the value of 1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4!. But, now the condition is i<=n, it will also include 1/5! into that 'sum' variable, which is wrong. So, how shall I modify the code ??

Comment: @Vega, 0! evaluates to 1, so 1/1 gives 1 and sum should print the value 1 if user gives 0 as input

Comment: @drescherjm how shall I modify the code so that it does floating type division ?? because when n is 2 or greater than 2, I want to take the decimal part into consideration also.

Comment: @Vega oh, sorry for not properly defining the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop the following way

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)
             ^^^^^
```

Or change the loop to do-while loop as for example

```
int i = 0;
do
{
    //...
} while ( i++ < n );
```

Also this statement

```
k = 1/p ;
```

change like

```
k = 1.0f/p ;
```

Comment: But, this condition(i<=n) makes the code wrong in the first place itself. In this series, 1/0! is 1st term, 1/1! is 2nd term and therefore, there are n+1 terms. Suppose, if user gives input 5(no of terms), the variable 'sum' should print the value of 1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4!. But, now the condition is i<=n, it will also include 1/5! into that 'sum' variable, which is wrong. That's why, I gave i<n.

Comment: @Got_R3kt The series is defined by the value of the denominator. So if n is equal to 5 then you should use the series 1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! + 1/5!

Comment: Okay, maybe you are right, but, the question itself says that n denotes the number of terms, so, if user gives input 5, then sum should give the value of  1/0! + 1/1! + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4!. Now the issue is how shall I modify the code??

Comment: It's working, Vlad. Btw, please explain what is the meaning of "1.0f" ?? I have no idea what you just did there :(

Comment: @Got_R3kt It is a float constant. Otherwise the expression is evaluated as an integer expression .

Comment: @Got_R3kt You could also use `1.` or `1.0` in place of `1.0f` to use `double` rather than `float` if you need that extra precision. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal